# Rails.cache.clear certain key names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, dalli

Is it possible to somehow run `Rails.cache.clear` and only clear keys with a certain name/string?

I don't want to clear the entire cache...just keys with the string `blog/post` in the name (ie. `blog/post/1`, `blog/post/2`).

I'm using [dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) with memcached for my cache and running Rails 3.0.6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer my own question...it seems that given I'm using memcached, I actually can't use `delete_if` or `delete_matched` because memcached does not support enumerating or querying keys by pattern ([1](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/40#issuecomment-530318)).

Comment: So, What is the solution while using memcache ?

Answer (score 132):

This is how you can write to cache -

```
Rails.cache.write('key', 'value', :time_to_idle => 60.seconds, :timeToLive => 600.seconds)
```

and in order to delete from cache you can use `delete` action -

```
Rails.cache.delete('key')
```

Delete multiple keys -

```
Rails.cache.delete_if {|k, v| k =~ 'key' }
```

Comment: Right, but I need to delete all keys that contain a certain string in their name. For instance, all keys that have `blog/post` in the name of the key.

Comment: @Shpigford `Rails.cache` is just a `hash` ..look for the hash documentation in order to delete multiple keys :)

Comment: I'm geting an 'undefined method' error for `delete_if`. I'm running Rails 3.0.6.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, I'm using Dalli w/ memcached as my cache.

Comment: time to idle and time to live seems for EH cache only http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-ehcachestore

Answer (score 3):

You can use the https://github.com/Phobos98/dalli-delete-matched gem that adds a simple implementation of `delete_matched` method for dalli store with memcached.

Comment: Does that work in a multi-server environment?  The gem looks like it stores the keys on the cache server without any guards to prevent multiple writers

Answer (score 0):

I add some dependency in the cache key, for example `Rails.cache.fetch("blog_#{blog.posts.order(:id).last.updated_at}_stat")`. So this key will expire automatically when any post changed.